# Showing points of continuity of a function $f(x)$ that takes the value $1/n$ whenever $x$ belongs to a sequence $\{A_n\}$ and is zero elsewhere.

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

I am given a sequence $(An), n=1,2,3,...$ which consists of distinct numbers, which converges to $3$ as $n$ tends to infinity, but none of its terms are equal to $3$.
Then I am given a function $f(x) = 1/n$  if $x=An$, $f(x)=0$ else
and I am asked to find the points of continuity of $f$ using the $ε-δ$ definition.

What I did:
For $x≠An$, $n∈ℕ$ : Let c be in an interval I that does not contain 3. Let $ε>0$ be given. Choose $δ>0$ such for $x∈ I, δ:=min{(|An-c|)}$, then we know that whenever $|x-c|<δ, |f(x)-f(c)|=|0-0|= 0 <ε$
Then I concluded that f is continuous at every $x$ such that $x≠An$.

For $x=3$: Let I be the interval containing the point 3. That 3 is the limit of the sequence (An),n∈ℕ means, given $ε>0 ,∃N ∈ℕ$ such that for all $n>N$, $|An-3|<ε$ . Set $δ:=ε$, then for all $x∈I$ satisfying $|x-3|<δ$, $|f(x)-f(3)| = |0-0| = 0 < ε$. So f is continuous at $x=3$.

For $x=An$: Let $An1$ and $An2$ be any two consecutive terms of the sequence in an interval I. Let $ε>0$, and let $δ>0$ be such that $δ:= min{(|An1-An2|)}$. Then we have that ∀x in I such that $|x-An2| < δ, |f(x)-f(An2)| = |0-1/n| = |1/n|$. We want that $|1/n|<ε$, but this will only occur for $n>N, N>1/ε$ . Then for all $n<N$, $f$ is not continuous at $An$. I concluded that $f$ is not continuous at all points where $x= An$.

What is the fallacy in my argument?

Comment: I don't read your arguments, but your conclusions seems to be OK.

Comment: You should justify why $\delta := \min(|A_n-c|)$ is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 such a delta is guaranteed to exist because since the sequence consists of distinct numbers, by the completeness of the set of real numbers, it is always possible to find a number, and a neighbourhood around it, which does not contain members of the sequence.